# Como colocar a data de hoje como valor padrão em um texbox como input tipo date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, input-type-date

Tenho uma página para pesquisa de um relatório de vendas e uso um `textbox` que gera um `input` tipo "date", e sempre que a página carrega o valor do campo fica "dd/mm/yyyy".

Gostaria que sempre que a página fosse carregada o campo mostrasse a data atual sem eu precisar abrir o calendário para escolher a data. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você está usando um [`DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx).

No evento `Page_Load`, creio que é só definir o campo com a data atual.

```
txtData.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

---

**EDIT**

Nos comentários, você está tendo como resultado em tela o seguinte:

```
<input name="calInicio" type="date" id="calInicio" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" style="height:32px;width:180px;">
```

O problema é que `<input type="date" ...>` [precisa ter como valor inicial uma data no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) (veja a parte que fala sobre `value`). Ou seja, no `Page_Load` carregue seu `TextBox` da seguinte forma:

```
txtInicio.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Eu coloquei isso na programação, mas quando ele carrega a página não adianta, coloquei isso -> txtInicio.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();  

O atributo Value não tem em um textbox

Comment: Ah, entendi. Vou editar a resposta. Antes quero entender: você faz uma inspeção no HTML e o `<input>` aparece pelo menos com um `value`? Ou não aparece nada?

Comment: Não aparece nada

Comment: O resultado no HTML por um acaso é `<input type="date" ...>`?

Comment: Fica assim:  <input name="calInicio" type="date" id="calInicio" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" style="height:32px;width:180px;">

Comment: Agora tudo faz sentido. Fique de olho. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Cara deu certo, muito obrigado !